# Not getting message from RabbitMQ Bus service

Tags: rabbitmq, asp.net-core-2.0, masstransit

I am working with RabbitMQ bus and Microservice. as i have 2 microservice. i am publish from 1 service and try to get that published message in 2nd service but i am not getting. here is my code.
Startup.cs -- Publisher, as i am using .net core and not putting whole file just put bus configuration

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Register(c =>
            {
                return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rmq =>
                {
                    var host = rmq.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                    rmq.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;
                });

            }).
             As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>()
            .As<IPublishEndpoint>()
            .SingleInstance();

            builder.Populate(services);
            ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
            var busControl = ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IBusControl>();
            busControl.Start();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
```

controller publish

```
_bus.Publish<OrderCompletedEvent>(new { BuyerId = Order.CustomerId.ToString() }).Wait();
```

Consumer StartUp

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // register a specific consumer
            builder.RegisterType<OrderCompletedEventConsumer>();
            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {


                    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "rabbitmqpocCart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), e =>
                    {
                        e.LoadFrom(context);
                        e.Consumer(() => new OrderCompletedEventConsumer());
                    });
                });

                return busControl;
            })
                .SingleInstance()
                .As<IBusControl>()
                .As<IBus>();
            builder.Populate(services);
            ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
            var busControl1 = ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IBusControl>();
            busControl1.Start();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
```

Consumer Service

```
    public class OrderCompletedEventConsumer : IConsumer<OrderCompletedEvent>
        {
            public OrderCompletedEventConsumer()
            {
            }

public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderCompletedEvent> context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(context.Message.BuyerId);
            await Test();

        }
            public async Task<bool> Test()
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

i had put debug in Consume Method but it's not hit. am i missing some thing. please help me.
i also note that both service make their on bus while application start. is it correct?

Please give me some good example link or documentation link.

Thank you

Comment: You are creating a new endpoint and bindings each time you start the app, because you are using new guid as part of the receive endpoint name. Your RabbitMQ will be out of disk space very soon.

Comment: I think we have enough documentation http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/autofac.html

Comment: You also tell MT about your consumer twice - once when you use `LoadFrom` and second time when you say `e.Consumer`. You need to choose one or another.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev thank you for reply, as i have update my code as per you said, but it's still not working.

Comment: There is likely a simple configuration mistake, but without the concise code base it's hard to tell. Can you create a GitHub repo with your failing code to help figure it out?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thank you for reply, as i fix this issue, it's silly mistake, my both microservice have different namespace for exchange name. so, but thanks for support